# Q-D scheme, continued fractions

Tags: continued-fractions

What is a Q-D scheme for a continued fraction? I am reading this text on numerical evaluation of the H-function and the author suggests using continued fractions as done by many other special functions. However, he shows this q-d scheme whose definition I cannot find.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the section of the paper I was referring to.[image: from the paper]

It was quite easy to understand and apply this, but it left wandering what is the Q-D scheme :)

Comment: you should identify the text and include an excerpt may reveal to people what you are talking about, and where else it might be found

Comment: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/approx/continuedfraction.html

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=1nwbtGQN4jcC&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=Q-D+scheme+for+a+continued+fraction&source=bl&ots=CRRf_xM6sL&sig=7vnXGuQZTCFrpSNHO8AP9WePNzw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwA2oVChMIkqm-o-jCyAIVTSmICh0PQQM0#v=onepage&q=Q-D%20scheme%20for%20a%20continued%20fraction&f=false

Comment: Oh, you found it! Thanks a lot! Curiosity was killing me. Please post it as answer so I can vote for it :)

Comment: we don't usually post answers that are just links. Further, I have no idea where you would find an introductory description of the technique in question, it has evidently been used, and expanded, for decades.